# How to execute shell commands through su?

Tags: java, android, android-shell

I tried following way but its not working for me :

```
public void RunAsRoot(String cmnd){
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());                        
        os.writeBytes(cmnd +"\n");                     
        os.writeBytes("exit\n");  
        os.flush();
        p.waitFor();
}
```

I tried this as well :

```
public void RunAsRoot(String cmds){
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c " + cmds);
        p.waitFor();
}
```

But none of the above method is working. However following command is working for me in shell through adb :

```
 su -c "input" " keyevent" " 3"
```

So I even tried this :

```
public void RunAsRoot(String cmds){
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c \"input\" \" keyevent\" \" 3\"");
        p.waitFor();
}
```

But even this didn't work. Can anyone please help me!!!!

Comment: do you want to run your java app in admin mode?

Answer (score 0):

I use an `OutputStream` instead of a `DataOutputStream`

```
sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null,null);
String now =  c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.HOUR)+":"+c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
Log.d(TAG, "Creating screenshot " + now +".png");
OutputStream  os = sh.getOutputStream();
os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + "/data/local/" + now +".png").getBytes("ASCII"));
os.flush();
os.close();
sh.waitFor();
```

Comment: is the device rooted?